# Is there a difference between "a=b" & "a=$b"?

Tags: shell-script

I came across two Unix scripts in my textbook. In one of them they implemented `a=$b` (in the form of max=$a) and in the other `a=b` (in the form of number=num).

Are these the same thing or is there a difference?

Comment: Could you provide us an example of the script please?

Comment: I am reasonably sure the textbook you are reading has an explanation of each.

Comment: The textbook I have is crap. It has lots of mistakes, so I tend to verify on the internet.

Comment: @Ketan It actually sounds like both cases intended to use the variable assignment (`a=$b`), and the latter case had a typo.  But a code snippet would help clarify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ a=b
$ printf $a
b
$ b=hello
$ a=$b  
$ printf $b
hello
```

Basically `a=b` makes a variable called `a` of which value is a literal `b`. `a=$b` makes a variable called `a` with the same value as an already existing variable called `b`.

Comment: I'd put b assignment to "hello" as the first line

Answer (score 3):

In case of, `a=$b` you are assigning the value of the variable `b` to `a`. While in case of `a=b` you are assigning `a` the value of the literal string "`b`"

E.g. `b=10`, Now suppose you want to assign `a` the same value as `b`. You can do either of the following:

```
a=$b
```

or,

```
a=10
```

Comment: "While in case of a=b you are assigning a the value b" So in case after using a=b we change the value of b then will a get automatically updated?

Comment: It was badly phrased; I have tweaked the answer to be more clear.

Answer (score 2):

You can ask `bash` for help in answering these questions too, using `set -x`. This flag tells bash to display the command and its expanded arguments before running it:

First, some setup:

```
$ a=some-value
$ b=some-other-value
$ set -x
```

Now let's see how the shell interprets these commands:

```
$ a=b
+ a=b
```

The value of the variable `a` is being set to the literal string "b".

Now let's try `$b`:

```
$ a=$b
+ a=some-other-value
```

Here we tell the shell to *evaluate* `$b` and insert the value of `b` into the command.

This shows some of the value of the shell -- it interprets variables and wildcards instead of making individual commands do the work. For example, `ls` doesn't have to know how to interpret "*.txt" because the shell does the work before `ls` is started:

```
$ ls *.txt
+ ls a.txt b.txt c.txt
a.txt  b.txt  c.txt
```